# Check previous value in dict while iterating

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got sorted by key dictionary in Python
I want check only previous value

for example

```
dict_n = {
1:'Smith',
3:'Martin',
7: 'Waterson',
...
9:'Davies',
13:'Smith',
15:'Smith'
}
```

I want find that before Smith (id=15) is also man named 'Smith' (id=13).  So I need get the value by key index (not by key-1) from a Python dictionary.

I tried to enumerate by index like list ( previous = list[index-1] ), but it doesn't work

```
for index, key in enumerate(Dict):
    print Dict[index]
```

Comment: Have you tried to iterate 2 key-value pairs at a time?

Comment: for k, v in Dict.iteritems() ?  - yes, but how I get previous pair? <hmm>

Comment: You can store the key at the end of that loop, at which point the loop gets the next one. The answer below looks like what you need

Comment: that's better idea ;) thx